# How to convert a number to unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order) in C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm looking for C# method that's equivalent to PHP pack()

I've found lot of articles about this on Google, but the result is always different than using my PHP code when I've tried some code.
I have no idea.

Here's my PHP code which I'd like to transfer in C# code.

`$binaryMagic = pack("n", 0xbabe);`

Comment: The question should be more precisely. For example: How to convert a number to unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order) in C#.

Comment: Thank you, changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should give you the same result:

```cs
string hex = "babe";
byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2) {
    bytes[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
}

string converted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I go with int decimal instead of the hex string ?

Comment: Then just fill the `bytes` array with the decimal values and skip the hex converter: `byte[] bytes = { 186, 190 };`

Comment: I need to write 4 byte integer, not a single byte.

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead?

Comment: Yes, but it use system endianess which give me different result